# TypeScript add static helper to prototype of existing class

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype

This is mainly a question on how to add/extend any existing type with `static` custom methods.

I want to have the `String` prototype extended with a function, e.g. `isNullOrEmpty` which should be invoked the `C#` way:

```
if(!String.isNullOrEmpty(myStringToCheck)){
    // do things as of myStringToCheck is set to something
}
```

In plain javascript I could do something like

```
String.isNullOrEmpty = function (s) {
    if (s == null || s === "")
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

But, when calling it inside a `TypeScript` it tells me

> The property 'isNullOrEmpty' does not exist on value of type '{ prototype: String; fromCharCode(...codes: number[]): string; (value?: any): string; new(value?: any): String; }'.

How can this be done so it is known by `TypeScript`?

**Edit #1**

How is `String.fromCharCode()` implemented which is already known by `TypeScript`?

**Edit #2**

Because of other dependencies in the project I'm currently only allowed to use `TypeScript 1.0`!

**Edit #3**

`String.d.ts`

```
interface StringConstructor {
    isNullOrEmpty(): boolean;
}

interface String {
    format(...args: any[]): string;
    isNullOrEmpty(): boolean;
}
```

and my `String.ts`

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/String.d.ts"/>

String.prototype.format = function (): string {
    var formatted = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var regexp = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gi");
        formatted = formatted.replace(regexp, arguments[i]);
    }
    return formatted;
}

String.isNullOrEmpty = function(s) { <-- here is the exception
    if (s == null || s === "")
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

**Solution #1** (`TypeScript` version > 1.0?)

> see first answer by MartyIX

**Solution #2** (workaround for `TypeScript` version 1.0)

> see second answer

Comment: You should mark your answer with the green tick. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As by comments from @MartyIX, it seems to be a problem with `TypeScript 1.0`.
As a workaround I've added a method to the prototype of `String`:

`String.d.ts` (definition)

```
interface String {
    isNullOrEmpty(text: string): boolean;
}
```

`String.ts` (implementation)

```
String.prototype.isNullOrEmpty = function(text) => {
    if (text == null || text === "")
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

which can be used

```
if(!String.prototype.isNullOrEmpty(myStringToCheck)){
    // do things as of myStringToCheck is set to something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// String.ts
interface StringConstructor {
    isNullOrEmpty(text: string): boolean;
}

interface String {
    isNullOrEmpty(text: string): boolean;
}

String.isNullOrEmpty = (s:string):boolean => {
    return (s == null || s === "");
};

// OtherFile.ts
///<reference path="path/to/String.ts" />

if(!String.isNullOrEmpty("test")){
    // Do something
}

var isEmpty = String.fromCharCode(100).isNullOrEmpty("Nah");
```

This works for me. The interface extends `StringConstructor`.

Comment: And how would I implement the method? I have a `String.ts` where I have some more extensions already implemented (but currently only new functions instead of `static` functions).

Comment: Please see the edited answer. You don't need to do anything fancy here. Just do what you would do in plain JavaScript.

Comment: This is not working. Is still says `The property 'isNullOrEmpty' does not exist on value of type '{ prototype: String; fromCharCode(...codes: number[]): string; (value?: any): string; new(value?: any): String; }'.` Maybe an version-issue?

Comment: What about the latest version?

Comment: See `Edit #3` - still not working with the same error-message. `StringConstructor` is also not known in `TypeScript 1.0` so I guess this is an issue

Comment: I don't see any reference to `String.d.ts` in `String.ts` in your code. For start, it may be a good idea to put it all in one file.

Comment: It was there. But not working. Even if all is packed into one file it is still not working

Comment: Well, if you my code to http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground, it works. Unfortunately, I don't have TypeScript 1.0, it's rather old.

Comment: Your example may work, but there are complier errors: [see playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Ainterface%20StringConstructor%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09isNullOrEmpty(text%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20String%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09isNullOrEmpty(test%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0AString.isNullOrEmpty%20%3D%20(test%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09return%20(!test%20%7C%7C%20!test.length)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: @prespic: The compiler error is gone when you remove "export" keyword. I don't work with latest version of TypeScript so I can't help further.

Comment: Yes, my fault. It is working now. Here is [fixed playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20StringConstructor%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09isNullOrEmpty(text%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20String%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09isNullOrEmpty(test%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AString.isNullOrEmpty%20%3D%20(test%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09return%20(!test%20%7C%7C%20!test.length)%3B%0D%0A%7D).