# Typescript, Is it possible to add method to external class prototype?

Tags: typescript, angular, prototype

Lets say, I want to add method to NgForm (class)

```
NgForm.prototype.markAsDirty = function (): void {
    let f: NgForm = this;
    Util.forEach(f.form.controls, (k, v: AbstractControl) => {
        v.markAsDirty(false);
    });
};
```

Is this somehow possible in typescript?

I am aware of:

- [TypeScript add static helper to prototype of existing class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119724/typescript-add-static-helper-to-prototype-of-existing-class)
- [Extending functionality in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897659/extending-functionality-in-typescript)
- [Extending Object.prototype with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813118/extending-object-prototype-with-typescript)

but it works only for interfaces, not classes.

Answer (score 7):

In Angular and TypeScript you usually use inheritance like

```
export class MyForm extends NgForm {
  ...
}
```

and register your custom class to be used throughout your application instead of the original class.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [FORM_PROVIDERS, FORM_DIRECTIVES, provide(NgForm, { useClass: MyForm})]);
```

I haven't investigated if there any additional things to consider that are special to the `NgForm`, `FORM_PROVIDERS` or `FORM_DIRECTIVES` to make this work properly.